# What does the "scope" parameter in filterContentForSearchText delegate method should contain?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have implemented filterContentForSearchText method in UISearchDisplayDelegate.

I can see that (NSString*)searchText is the text i write in the textfield, but the scope returns me NULL. What parameter do I give for scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope is the "area" in which you are searching, if you have implemented it. E.g.

[image: Search with scope bar]

You can then pass the relevant scope to `filterContentForSearchText:scope:` as follows:

```
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString 
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
```

This was taken from [Apple's TableSearch sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: I still don't quit get the "area" means. Is that true if there is only one search bar on screen then I don't have to bother with scope?